# VS2017 Intellisense is slow and sometimes it crashes, any suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm working with the community edition of VS2017.
Version 15.2(26430.14) which is the latest update as of 07/Jul/2017.
Intellisense is sporadically slow, and stops normal progress of my coding effort.  It seems to "wake up" after about a 10 to 20 second wait.  But today, it crashed, and the activity log showed this information.

```
 <entry>
<record>1709</record>
<time>2017/07/06 00:17:33.497</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot Match.  The session is dismissed.&#x000D;&#x000A;   
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CompletionSession.Match()&#x000D;&#x000A;  
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CompletionSession.OnViewBuffer_Changed(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e)&#x000D;&#x000A;  
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)
```

At the time I was editing XAML and adding a Binding to the IsOpen property of a ContextMenu. After closing the editor and reopening, it worked fine...

I've removed all Plug-ins but Code Maid, which I'll try next.  However, I'm looking for suggestions to this hiccup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this problem was the new version of CCleaner Cloud Edition. Once I removed this software the problem all intellisense slowness and crashes ceased!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. I closed Visual Studio and deleted the .vs (hidden) folder and restarted. It automatically regenerated the folder.

Comment: Chet, where is that folder located?

Comment: Inside the solution folder.

Comment: The solution above works but only for a short time, although Intellisense times are better they're still not what they should be...  Intellisense should not affect performance while coding.... in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue with this as well.  See Link (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues-product-crashes-or-rendering-issues)

It looks to be an issue with some display drivers causing issues.  The recommended workaround is to disable hardware acceleration for VS2017.  I did this and it fixed my issues.  Intellisense is now working as fast as I can type.

I have attached a screenshot from the link for the workaround just in case the link becomes dead.

[image: Intellisense Workaround]

Comment: For me it was just disabling the automatic adjusting. Whether it uses GPU or not, now id does not seem any different. Working on gaming pc.