# Visual Studio 2017: Speed up C++ IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I use a header only library in my C++ project.

**When I make a change** in my code, Visual Studio starts parsing files in my solution, including the included library.

Since the library is big, parsing it is slow and **I have to wait for a long time until IntelliSense becomes relevant** again.

Is there a way to speed up this parsing, perhaps, by excluding the library from IntelliSense?

This question is NOT a duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 is too slow during building and debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877071/visual-studio-2017-is-too-slow-during-building-and-debugging) because it deals specifically with speeding up IntelliSense, which is not touched by the other question, nor it's answers.

Comment: Let it parse it once and then it will probably work faster.

Comment: Are you using pre-compiled header technique or not?

Comment: @Sheen My Precompiled Header setting is set to `Use (/Yu)`. However, I believe the precompiled header only contains the standard library. How do I include other libaries in this? Will this speed up IntelliSense as well as build?

Comment: @Draex_ I am not sure if it will speed up IntelliSense. You #include all the header files you won't oftenly change into stdafx.h. They are not necessarily STL headers. They can be any header file.

Answer (score 7):

This seemingly unrelated issue fixed slow IntelliSense for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401328/6800366

- Go to Options > Environment > General
- Uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance"
- Uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available"

Maybe unchecking "Enable rich client visual experience" also helps for you. It made no difference for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase Rescan Solution interval in the VS settings. Goto **Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced** and set **Rescan Solution interval** to desired minutes. I prefer 5000. The value must be between 0 and 5000.

> Changes you make are parsed in real time (ie: as you make them),
>   however every set amount of time a complete parse is triggered to
>   ensure that the whole database is up to date. This extra parse won’t
>   actually clean up your database and recreate it from scratch but
>   rather scan for changes made on files that are not active (take for
>   example opening one of the header files your project is referencing on
>   a different instance of Visual Studio). By default this is every 60
>   minutes, by changing this you can control that interval.

Comment: It is actually: Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced  (VS Community 2017, 15.6.19)

Answer (score 1):

1) Visual settings, 2) re-scan interval and 3) deletion of project cache made limited (if any for 1,2) effects in my case.

---

Then I start playing with **Automatic Precompiled Header Cache Quota** (*Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced*). In first step I've increased it from default 50Gb to 75gb - guess what: it became slower and slower. Once cache directory (*[solution directory].vs*) reached the limit - IntelliSense became completely useless.

If you think: really, how 50gb-75gb of precompiled code could lead to faster IntelliSense? Such amount of data has to be indexed, queried... maintained. 
**Setting limit to 10Gb made my day**. IntelliSense became responsive as it should be.

---

I have to point out that issue is not limited to VS2017, but also occurs in VS2019. This issue actually made me trying VS2019. While VS2019 is really much better with C++ than VS2017, it has the same problem with project cache. Also, it is important to say that this is not only VS C++ issue, I had same/similar problem with project cache [.vs] back in my C# years. It is just more drastic with C++ projects due language specifics.